# split search results in to pages

Tags: php, xml, search

Hi I want to split search results into pages. But I am using different kind of search code. This code will search an xml file and show the results. So how do I turn the results to pages ? From this link where I got the code for this search engine. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [Pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). There are [lots of great tutorials to get get you started](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=pagination%20php#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=Q9dvm6fYbS268rdCaLKj9Q&pq=pagination%20&cp=16&gs_id=s&xhr=t&q=php%20pagination%20tutorial&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=php%20pagination%20t&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ecb6a798695883bc&biw=1366&bih=667).